# Django Bash completion not working on manage.py

Tags: python, django, bash-completion, django-manage.py

I am trying out the `django_bash_completion` script provided by Django but can't use it with `python manage.py` command.

I am trying out the `django_bash_completion` script provided by Django. I have added it to active script in the virtual environment. It works with `django-admin` but can't use it with `python manage.py` command.

```
cd django-test-project
virtualenv -p python3 venv
echo "source /path/to/.django_bash_completion" >> venv/bin/active
active
django-admin<tab><tab>
python manage.py<tab><tab>
```

For `django-admin` it shows all options like `check`, `makemigrations`, `migrate` `runserver` etc but when I run `python manage.py` it gives `manage.py: command not found`.

Any idea why and how can I solve it?

I am running bash on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: `manage.py` is available at the project level. You need to `cd` to the desired project.

Comment: @shafik I am already on the project level directory. updated the question.

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/extras/django_bash_completion

Comment: @Sahil the `.django_bash_completion` file I mentioned is downloaded from the source you commented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to run `manage.py <tab><tab>` not `python manage.py <tab><tab>`

As the Official Documentation says: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#bash-completion

Comment: I had to run `chmod a+x manage.py` to make `manage.py` executable, and the completion would only work when running `./manage.py <tab>` (this is on macOS)

Comment: I tried this but it is not working? Have you tested it on ubunutu?

Comment: new code uses `grep` instead of `egrep`... i believe thats the problem. try old bash script i've posted.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this old original bash-completion for Django. still works :) you don't need to ./manage.py ... try `python manage.py [tab]`

https://gist.github.com/vigo/5c25936a682845932bdaf17126c4167d

tested on macOS Ventura, python 3.11.0 + Django 4.1.3